# Parental control on OSX causing problems

Tags: json, macos, symfony, parental-control

I'm encountering a really weird problem with OSX's parental control feature. If turned on, all requests to JSON resources on our application get aborted. A few facts:

- The URLs look like this: `http://some.domain.net/exercise/1-1.json`
- It doesn't matter if the resource is loaded via Ajax or if the URL is called directly
- The request reaches the server which successfully sends a response back (according to apache logs)
- Whitelisting URLs doesn't help. In fact, I can even enable "allow unrestricted access to websites" - As long as the parental control is active, the resource can't be loaded
- The problem has nothing to do with certain keywords in the URL (e.g. `http://some.domain.net/bleh.json` also gets blocked)
- Our application is based on Symfony2 but I don't think that matters

I'm almost sure that it's not a bug with the parental control feature in general, because I couldn't find anything like that on Google - So I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: Did you test the file content against a profanity filter? You say it's not the Url, but perhaps the content looks too dirty for the filter?

Comment: In my experience the parental controls on OSX can be very finicky. Have you tried on a brand new account with the parental controls setup?

Comment: It might help us to know which specific settings you have enabled in parental controls. What are they?

Comment: @zchrykng Yes, that's exactly what I did

Comment: @musicin3d That's the fun part, even if I enable "allow unrestricted access to websites" the resource gets blocked. So I guess the other settings don't matter?

Comment: @elHornair have you tried logging out and then back in after switching to allow unrestricted access?

Comment: @zchrykng Yes, I did - Doesn't change anything :(

Comment: @HannesGassert Good catch. The content is fine however.

Answer (score 1):

After an update on our testing machine (OSX 10.8.5) the problem vanished (I suspect the package "Security Update 2014-001" is responsible for this). So if you run into the same problem, try to update your system.